# How to apply search criteria (specification) on jpa repository custom methods?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

How can I apply search specification on repository methods?

here is my code

```
@Repository
public interface JourneyRepository extends JpaRepository<Journey, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Journey> {

    Page<Journey> findAllByDriverId(Long id, Pageable pageable);
}
```

I want to apply search criteria specification on findAllByDriverId

Answer (score 0):

findByType pattern is provide by [spring data jpa](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.x/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html).  JpaSpecificationExecutor Only support follwing inferface. If you want findAllByDriverId just use spring data jpa.

```
public interface JpaSpecificationExecutor<T> { 
     T findOne(Specification<T> spec); 
     List<T> findAll(Specification<T> spec); 
     Page<T> findAll(Specification<T> spec, Pageable pageable); 
     List<T> findAll(Specification<T> spec, Sort sort); 
     long count(Specification<T> spec); 
}
```

I think you don't need JpaSpecificationExecutor, and I guess DriverId is in Journey? Then include spring-boot-starter-data-jpa

```
public interface JourneyRepository extends JpaRepository<Journey, Long> {

   Page<Journey> findAllByDriverId(Long id, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Comment: can you please be specific in my case on findByType (i mean spring data jpa). what i need to use for this in my code

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can by using @Query annotation above the method in the repository for example:

```
@Query(value="select * from Journey where [name of the field] = ?1",
       countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM Journey WHERE [name of the field] = ?1",
       nativeQuery = true)
Page<Journey> findAllByDriverId(Long id, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: I need to search from all fields of Journey table. and it's around 20 fields in that

Comment: What did you mean by search from all fields?

Comment: means if user enters anything it will search from all columns of journey table

Answer (score 0):

You could use for your case JPA Criteria with spring data JPA, look at the link below it will give you what you are looking for:

[full description](https://kalliphant.com/spring-data-jpa-dynamic-queries/)